# Is there a way to get user information by pinging someone in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a command in my discord.js file that allows users to vote for someone using a !vote @user command. Whenever I print out @user, I get `<@!user_id>`. Is there a way to turn that value into something manipulatable to for example, get @users's username or mute them in a voice call like when using `msg.user`?

```
client.on('message', msg) {
   if (msg.content.startsWith('!')) {
      let command = msg.content.substring('!'.length);
      let ping = command.split(' ');

      if(command == 'vote') {
         // Convert <@!user_id> into a manipulatable user?
         let user_information = ping[1]
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at `<Message>.mentions.users.first()`? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`message.mentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users)

Like this:

```js
const mention = message.mentions.users.first();
```

Or if you wanted the member you could use [`message.mentions.members.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) like:

```js
const mention = message.mentions.members.first();
```

If you don't want to use that you could use [discord.js's guide on parsing mentions](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html)